# Can't create an auto_increment primary key, when there is a foreign key which is auto_inc in origin

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I've got 2 tables:

1. INCIDENCIES:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE incidencies
     (
        id_inc     INT(7) ZEROFILL NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
        empresa    VARCHAR(40),
        maquina    VARCHAR(20),
        tipus_inc  VARCHAR(20),
        estat_mon  VARCHAR(20),
        estat_inc  VARCHAR(20),
        dia_inc    DATE,
        hora_inc   TIME,
        descripcio VARCHAR(200)
     )
   CHARACTER SET utf8
   engine=innodb;
   ```
2. COMENTARIS:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE comentaris
     (
        id_inc    INT(7) ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
        id_com    INT(3) ZEROFILL NOT NULL auto_increment,
        data_com  DATE,
        hora_com  TIME,
        comentari VARCHAR(999),
        PRIMARY KEY(id_inc, id_com),
        FOREIGN KEY (id_inc) REFERENCES incidencies (id_inc) ON DELETE CASCADE ON
        UPDATE CASCADE
     )
   CHARACTER SET utf8
   engine=innodb;
   ```

As you can see, on `COMENTARIS` table, `ID_INC` is a foreign key which on its origin is auto_incremental, but is not anymore on `COMENTARIS`.

Now I do want to make the field `ID_COM` auto_incremental, and make both of them primary keys.

The table should look like this:

```
ID_INC | ID_COM
001    |  001
001    |  002
001    |  003
002    |  004
003    |  005
```

The problem is that it seems MySQL detects `ID_INC` as an auto_incremental field, which is **not** on `COMENTARIS` table anymore.

When I try to make `ID_COM` auto_incremental, I get this error message:

> ERROR 1075 (42000): Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

The database needs to be `InnoDB` engine.

Any solution?

Comment: If `ID_INC` is a foreign key in `COMENTARIS`, then it doesn't make any sense for it to be `AUTO_INCREMENT` (or even primary key) in that table.  It sounds like you need to read up on what primary and foreign keys actually are.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not related to foreign keys. If this is all the code you run:

```
CREATE TABLE comentaris
(
    id_inc    INT(7) ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
    id_com    INT(3) ZEROFILL NOT NULL auto_increment,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_inc, id_com)
)
engine=innodb;
```

... you still get the same error.

In order to be able to use `AUTO_INCREMENT` on `id_com` you need to have a key where `id_com` is either the first item or the only item. So far, you only have the primary key where `id_com` is the *second* item—that's not enough because MySQL cannot use that index for this purpose.

I have the impression that you have a typo and you really want this:

```
CREATE TABLE comentaris
(
    id_inc    INT(7) ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
    id_com    INT(3) ZEROFILL NOT NULL auto_increment,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_com)
)
engine=innodb;
```